# Tree Capturing problem where to place another player for maximum score

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Given a binary tree. Two players are playing a game, at every time both the players simultaneously captures all neighbouring nodes.
At the time where no player can capture anymore nodes the game is over and the result is calculated.

If a player captures neighbouring nodes all those nodes are considered to be of that player.

Given the node of player1 where should the player2 be placed so that player2 gets the maximum amount of nodes.

If there is a problem of common neighbour consider no one captures it.

I searched over the internet and can't find any similar question

At start of the game you can consider it as a forest.

Comment: This question isn't very clear; does "at every time" mean the players aren't playing in turns? What are the nodes they capture neighbouring? Are there any rules about which nodes are allowed to be captured, or can the players just keep capturing and recapturing the same nodes? Please try to edit it to describe the problem more clearly, and ask something specific about it.

Comment: @kaya3 They both simultaneously does captures all neighbouring nodes. Edited the question as well.

Comment: You did not answer all the points that kaya raised. Where is a player positioned after grabbing "all" neighbors? What are considered their neighbors on their second move? Or is there only one move? When a node is captured, is it removed from the tree, making it a forest? Is the node that is occupied by a player considered "grabbed"? ...etc. This question is lacking a lot of specification.

Comment: @trincot does it need further edits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood the rules, then it would make sense to position the second player on one of the nodes neighboring the first player node.

Because the graph is a tree, every internal node is an articulation point: by capturing such a node, the graph actually splits into disconnected graphs. So with two players present, one player can only reach the nodes that are in one of the disconnected graphs that the other player generates.

Let's imagine that player one is on an internal node with two children and a parent. That player has thus divided the graph into three disconnected graphs: the left subtree, the right subtree, and finally all the nodes that can be reached from the parent node, but not via the player's node.

The other player can only be placed in one of those three graphs. The first player will have free access to the other two. There is no way the second player can have an influence there. So this means it is best to place the second player in the largest of the three disconnected graphs. The choice of the node in that disconnected graph is simple: take the one that is directly accessible by the first player, so that they cannot even "enter" that disconnected graph. The second player thereby "owns" that tree, and can capture it completely.

So a possible algorithm would need to get the size of the three disconnected graphs that are neighboring a player's node. First define use a simple recursive algorithm to get the size of a (sub)tree:

```py
function getSizeTree(root):
    if root == NIL:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + getSizeTree(root.left) + getSizeTree(root.right)
```

Then for a given `root` of the tree, and a node where the first `player1` is placed, we can determine the best choice for `player2` as follows:

```py
function getBestForPlayer2(root, player1):
    sizeAll = getTreeSize(root)
    sizeLeft = getTreeSize(player1.left)
    sizeRight = getTreeSize(player1.right)
    sizeParent = sizeAll - sizeLeft - sizeRight - 1

    maxSize = max(sizeLeft, sizeRight, sizeParent)
    if sizeLeft == maxSize:
        player2 = root.left
    else if sizeParent == maxSize:
        player2 = root.parent
    else:
        player2 = root.right
    return player2
```

Comment: Can we optise it further, I don't think but interviewer told me to optimise it further.

Comment: No. You need at least to visit all nodes to count them (unless your tree holds such extra info). This algorithm visits the nodes once. It has linear time complexity.